# How to avoid one webview stop other one video? android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, audio, webview

the situation: I have an app that load two webviews on the same activity half screen each, one on youtube one on twitch.

the problem: everithing works fine but, when both webviews are complete loaded if i unmuted twitch one, and then press play or pause, each webview stop the other one. (sorry my english)

i mean... when app load, both webviews play simultaneusly, if i unmuted both all works fine, but, if i press play/pause on youtube's webview the twitch webview stop playing, and if i press play/pause on twitch's webview the youtube's webview stop playing.

the code is really simple and i dont implement anything about audiomanager.

```
val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.youtube)
    myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    val webSettings = myWebView.settings

    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
    myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
    val newUA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
    myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA)
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNELYOUTUBE&color=white&enablejsapi=1&widgetid=1&muted=1&autoplay=0")
    myWebView.setOnTouchListener({ v, event -> true })





    val myWebView2: WebView = findViewById(R.id.twitch)
    myWebView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    val webSettings2 = myWebView2.settings
    webSettings2.javaScriptEnabled = true
    myWebView2.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    myWebView2.loadUrl("https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=CHANNELTWITCH&parent=twitch.tv")
```

I want to have the two webviews playing at same time but i havent clue on how to get this working.